# Why doesn't X11/XQuartz start on Lion?

Tags: macos, x11

After upgrading to Lion, X11 doesn't start. I downloaded XQuartz 2.7.0, it doesn't start either.

The crash dialog mentions the following problem:

> X11:
>   Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: X11.bin requires version 21.0.0 or later, but libpixman-1.0.dylib provides version 17.0.0

> XQuartz:
>   Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: /opt/X11/*/libfreetype.6.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: X11.bin requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 10.0.0

Unsetting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't help either.

EDIT: I also reinstalled X11 from the Lion installer package as described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3484517?start=0&tstart=0), but the problem is the same.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did the result of the otool command suggested by @esarjeant change?

Comment: Strangely, the problem fixed itself (10.7.3). I don't know which update caused it, but it works now...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the GnuPlot package delivers an older version of libfreetype.6.dylib than is installed on Lion (or SnowLeopard, in my case).

```
otool -L /Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib 
/Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib:
    /tmp/gnuplot-i386/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.2.0)
```

Yet my error is that GnuPlot is trying to load "/usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib" and not the library contained in the GnuPlot package. That library is the right version:

```
otool -L /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib 
/usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib:
    /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 14.0.0, current version 14.2.0)
```

This is as far as I have gotten. I did note that the library aliases in the GnuPlot package all point to the libraries delivered with GnuPlot (4/15/2011 in my case), so my next trick will be to create a new alias for libfreetype.6.dylib pointing to the one in /usr/X11/lib and see if I get a new error.

Maybe the answer is to build GnuPlot on our Macs?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open /Applications/Utilities/X11, which opens a web page that tells you to install Xquartz).
2. Install XQuartz. This will change X11 to /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.
3. Launch Gimp and a picker dialog, titled Where is X11? opens listing the apps from /Applications.
4. From the picker dialog, click Browse button, and choose /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.
5. XQuartz will show in the dock.
6. Quit Gimp and XQuartz.
7. At this point, the link to X11 should be setup properly so that launching Gimp automatically launches XQuartz .

Answer (score 0):

A quick check of OS X Lion shows:

> $ otool -L /usr/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib
>   /usr/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib:     /usr/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib
>   (compatibility version 21.0.0, current version 21.2.0)
>     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 159.1.0)

If your libpixman-1.0 library has something different (i.e.: not version 21.x.x), you may want to re-install X11 from the Lion CD.

Comment: My output:
/usr/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib:
 /usr/X11/lib/libpixman-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 21.0.0, current version 21.2.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)

Lion doesn't ship with a CD, but is installable from the App Store...

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this by changing the GnuPlot libfreetype library to point at the system one:

```
# Change to your GnuPlot install directory...
$ cd /Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/lib
# Backup the provided libfreetype...
$ mv libfreetype.6.dylib libfreetype.6.dylib.bak
# Link to the X11 provided one...
$ ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib .
```